# How do I fix eroded rectangles?

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing, qt4, masking

Basically, I have an image like this
[image]

or one with multiple rectangles within the same image. The rectangles are completely black and white have "dirty" edges and gouges, but it's pretty easy to tell they're rectangles. To be more precise, they are image masks. The white regions are parts of the image which are to be "left alone", but the black parts are to be made bitonal.

My question is, how do I make a nice and crisp rectangle out of this degraded one? I am a Python person, but I *have* to use Qt and C++ for this task. It would be preferable if no other libraries are used.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the rectangles always aligned to the outer rectangle, or might you have (for example) a square turned 45 degrees, giving a diamond-like shape (even though it still has square corners and straight sides)?

Comment: Though not targetting c++, some of the answers on [how to detect blobs and crop them in png files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783857/how-to-detect-blobs-and-crop-them-into-png-files/4784260#4784260) is probably very relevant to this problem.

Comment: Well, this is a simple case ;) I am aiming at just finding the bounding box of all the shapes (they are mostly rectangles and ovals, but you get the occasional random shape) individually to minimize image corrosion.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin, they are all big, white non-intersecting rectangles with little to no rotation.

Comment: @Blender regarding your last comment, different geometries require different algorithms. An oval (ellipse) is not detected by the same algorithm you detect a rectangle, at least not the optimal one. Therefore, if you have requirements for other geometries, I suggest to update the question!

Comment: Well, I basically just want to focus on this case. My current idea is to just do a plain ol' image segmentation (or whatever you call it) to extract the shapes, and then just overwrite them with a white rectangle.

Comment: Are you trying to find the bounding box of the while pixels?

Comment: Yes, basically. I think reconstructing a shape is too difficult, and the bounding box here is basically the shape itself, so that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bounding box that contains all non-black pixels can do what you want, this should do the trick:

```
int boundLeft = INT_MAX;
int boundRight = -1;
int boundTop = INT_MAX;
int boundBottom = -1;
for(int y=0;y<imageHeight;++y) {
    bool hasNonMask = false;
    for(int x=0;x<imageWidth;++x) {
        if(isNotMask(x, y)) {
            hasNonMask = true;
            if(x < boundLeft) boundLeft = x;
            if(x > boundRight) boundRight = x;
        }
    }
    if(hasNonMask) {
        if(y < boundTop) boundTop = y;
        if(y > boundBottom) boundBottom = y
    }
}
```

If the result has negative size, then there's no non-mask pixel in the image. The code can be more optimized but I haven't had enough coffee yet. :)

Comment: YESSS! This is so much less painful than including OpenCV (stops `svn`)! I will post back to confirm that it works.

Comment: And it works! I just fixed those `++y` statements and added some stuff, but it works. And no need for OpenCV! Thanks!

Comment: Oops. Knew it's not just un-optimized. Sorry for the typo and glad that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'd do that by repeatedly dilating and eroding the mask. I don't think qt has premade functions for that, so you probably have to implement them yourself if you don't want to use libraries - http://ostermiller.org/dilate_and_erode.html has information on how to implement the functions.

Comment: I tried it with GIMP, and it seems to get rid of the noise around the huge gouges. That's one step closer :D! Now how would I fill those gouges? Time for some more Google-ing...

Comment: If you do it enough times, or choose a bigger radius, it will eventually fill up those gouges.

Comment: I just noticed that gimp does it not like the page i linked to does. You'll need to make it so that it only switches the 4 nearest neighbours of a pixel, not the 4 that share only a corner with the pixel.

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, we'll assume they're all supposed to come out as rectangles with no rotation. In this case, you should be able to use a pretty simple approach. Starting from each pixel at the edge of the bitmap, start sampling pixels working your way inward until you encounter a transition. Record the distance from the edge for each transition (if there is one). Once you've done that from each edge, you basically "take a vote" -- the distance that occurred most often from that edge is what you treat as that edge of the rectangle. If the rectangle really is aligned, that should constitute a large majority of the distances.

If, instead you see a number of distances with nearly equal frequencies, chances are that the rectangle is rotated (or at least one edge is). In this case, you can divide the side in half (for example) and repeat. Once you've reached a large majority of points in each region agreeing on the distance, you can (attempt to) linearly interpolate between them to give a straight line (and limiting the minimum region size will limit the maximum rotation -- if you get to some size without reaching agreement, you're looking at a gouge, not the rectangle edge). Likewise, if you have a region (or more than one) that doesn't fit cleanly with the rest and won't fit with a line, you should probably ignore it as well -- again, you're probably looking at a gouge, not what's intended as an edge.

Comment: Thanks! That gave me a great idea, which is a simpler version of your algorithm (I will use your's later. It is perfect for geometric shapes): Start from left edge, and "shoot" lines until they hit a white pixel. Average those distances (excluding outliers, such as lines which don't "hit" any white pixels) and you have the right distance of the rectangle from the image's side. Repeat for the rest of the directions (this will fail if you have a big gouge).

Comment: @Blender Good approach. I think that if you use the median instead of the average you will solve the problem with the outliers.

Comment: I think'll I'll just settle with @Stephen Chu's answer. It does what I want (I don't want to chop off little pixels, as that might give the color image a bitonal border), and it's conceptually simple. But your method will be used for the other complex shapes!